# My video can't be indexed: does it impact the SEO of the page on which it appears?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

The google search console tells me that some of the videos on my site cannot be indexed.
The main reason is that

> The video is outside the viewport

This isn't really a problem because I don't really need these videos to be indexed in Google results. Therefore I don't want to change my pages to put the videos in the viewport, just to satisfy Google.

However, I'm wondering if the fact that the video can't be indexed has any impact on the SEO of the page on which it appears.
Because if that's the case, I might want to resolve those google notifications to prevent the SEO of those pages from plummeting.

The only resource I could find on this subject is [this answer on Google support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/221750117?hl=en&msgid=221846485).
The answer seems to be: No, the fact that the video is indexed or not does NOT impact the page's SEO.
But I don't know if I can really trust this one answer found online.